# Is it advisable to write a server application in pure Ruby code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I am trying to develop a server application that interacts with web services.

Since it is "hard" to develop that using the Ruby on Rails framework because there are many complications on the way (e.g.: classe encapsulation using namespaces), is it advisable to write the server application entirely in pure Ruby code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't advocate using Ruby on Rails as a persistent server, as it's completely engineered for a web-based request-driven approach, but Ruby is a perfectly fine language to pursue that sort of thing in.

[eventmachine](http://rubyeventmachine.com/) is a great place to start as it has a number of example modules that implement [standard services](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/wiki/Protocol-Implementations) like SMTP, DNS and Websocket.

It really depends on what kind of a server you're trying to build.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [Node.js](http://nodejs.org) for quick yet fast servers. Node is evented and is really easy to get a functional server up and running.  Most of us know enough Javascript to work with Node.  Check the docs at the site I linked - may work out.

It is pretty 'new' though and is changing/evolving fast - that may be an issue.

For me I just use what I know and keep an eye out for road blocks.  Ruby + Event Machine is a really solid choice as well.